# Only copies first two files

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I'm trying to copy all 4 of these files, however, only the first 2 are being copied.

```
scp /home/car02fv/dbg_a.`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log dbg_b.`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log dbg_c.`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log dbg_d.`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log user@host:/home/car02fv/
```

Comment: That tells me your *command substitution* is incorrect for the other two?

Comment: Only the first file gets the `/home/car02fv/` path, the others are assumed to be in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you trying to push or pull the files?  Going with just what you added, I can see 2 problems.

1. You have an open quote in the dates that don't have a corresponding close quote.
2. You have to full path each file.

You might try this and see if it resolves your issue.  I'm an amateur compared to most on this site, but doing it this way worked for me.

```
scp /home/car02fv/dbg_a.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /home/car02fv/dbg_b.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /home/car02fv/dbg_c.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /home/car02fv/dbg_d.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log user@host:/home/car02fv/
```

Comment: yes this works. Thank you. Also, I'm trying to pull files.

Comment: you might take a look at this website.  This is what I used for a while to help me understand scp

http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php